# I can't find a keyboard tat suits me, how much to build a batch of 1000 custom keyboards in China?

Tags: keyboards

I'm sorry if I post in the wrong SE Site but I think this is the one that fits the best.
So here is my question:
**What is the minimal batch size that is required to manufacture a custom keyboard in China?**

I guess the answer is : it depends.
I can make an unique keyboard but it will cost a lot of money.

Is a batch of 1000 a viable expectation? Or does it need more (because of molding)?

By custom, I mean a little more than branding.
It will be a high-grade full-size keyboard (Think Apple A1243 or bleujour keyboard)

- good typing quality (no loose key)
- no ghosting
- aluminium/metal front plate
- bluetooth
- 2 usb port at unconventional place
- removable cord
- slim, slim, slim and more slim
- chiclet scissor
- backlit (mono but different intensities)

optional:

- hub functionnality (usb2)
- slot for charging rechargeable batteries (Ni-Mh ?)
- color backlit

Price goal for 1000 would be 90$ each (plus shipping) via direct sales (no benefits made on the keyboard).
No printed fancy box

Comment: You don't seem to have considered the R&D, design & tooling cost, nor that you can't run USB let alone charging off bluetooth. Just buy an A1243 & be done with it.

Comment: What R&D ? What Design ? Middle plate + keys come as a all-in-one (google laptop keyboard replacement)  then you need a top plate (I'll go for standard design but premium quality) the back plate (this is more annoying) and the driver card. Maybe driver card will need some minor tweaking (cord to move away the usb where they re not supposed to be)

Comment: So, not a custom build, made from existing assemblies, bolted together in a custom order. You'll still need a custom case. In one job, we used to get runs of 1000 made for that type of task. [In another job we specced in millions]. idk pricing because I worked in 'spec' not 'cost'. It did involve someone flying to China several times for meetings, tooling & R&D structures etc. I think you're in way over your head. Your landed cost of $90 is actually easy to achieve, once you have your spec & tooling. Anything that sells retail for $100 cost $10 to ship, otherwise it's not profitable.

Comment: I don't make it for a profit. I go for 1000 because it sounds like the good number. It's not that high that I fear I couldn't sell it and it's not that low that I think no manufacturer would even consider (or will charge so much it won't make any sense). Consider (the cost) of flying to China is not a problem (= 0). I expected the cost of R&D / tooling to be null. Except for : topcase (replace plastic with metal), driver board (need to connect board pinout to usb socket located at unusual place (ribbon should be ok), backplate that needs a bit of customization (secure the usb, holes)

Comment: Sorry for my first comment that sounded a bit harsh now that I looked at it. I should have make clear I'm not doing a DYI unique sample but rather go the step after that is go for some kind of "mass" production.